Elastic Dense vector Index Size
I am a novice in the field and trying to understand Elasticsearch's vector search product. I am trying to size a project of 2M vectors with 384 dimensions. I heard that Elastic stores values as 8 bytes. In that case what would be the size of the index roughly to size the node ram size for the cluster. A quick math of 2 x 384 x 4 = 3TB - so should I be looking for the price of a node that has atleast 3TB of RAM?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-knn-search.html is a great starting point for this and you are going in the right direction. The general formula is num_vectors * 4 * (num_dimensions + 12) for the current default of float (4 bytes for each vector), which should come out to about 3GB. Though you'll want a second copy (replica shard) for high availability, so you'll need to double that to 6GB. And this is what you'll need for off-heap memory, where you'll need more for on-heap (with the right settings and hardware profile).
You could enable quantization which will automatically recalculate to byte precision (so 1 instead of 4 bytes) to drastically reduce your memory requirements; though it will need a bit more disk space for the vectors (the sum of quantized and original). But the bottleneck is normally memory so I wouldn't worry too much about the disk.

The size of the vector and index is changing from case to case because the data is changing. Instead estimating the total size it'd be better to test it. Take a reasonable percentage of your data, index it and see the result!
An example for you:
In this article, A 60MB TSV file, Microsoft MARCO Passage Ranking full data set, contains 182,469 text passages indexed into Elasticsearch as vectors. With dense vector in source it tooks 360MB in disk space.
